# Illegal string offset 'tmp_name' cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, offset

I have a big problem, i can't upload a file in cakephp, i have an error:

```
 if(!empty($this->request->data['Pictures']['name'])){
            $foto_name=$this->request->data['Pictures']['name'];

            $foto_tmp = $this->request->data['Pictures']['name']['tmp_name'];
            $path=WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'myimage'.$foto_name;
            move_uploaded_file($foto_tmp, $path);


        }
```

and the error is :

```
Warning (2): Illegal string offset 'tmp_name'
```

i don't understand why?

Comment: `$foto_tmp = $this->request->data['Pictures']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: @SofyanThayf this is not what i need,if i will do this i will have another error **Undefined index: tmp_name ** i have in html Picture.name thats why i need this.

Comment: Please add your from section code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Only

```
$temp_name = $this->request->data['Pictures']['tmp_name'];
```